# How to implement a swipeView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have two activity layout and i would like to implement a swipeView in Android between two layouts.

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.finalproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class FinalProjectActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_project);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_final_project, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can see this http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-swipeview/ library for implementing swipview in android

Comment: You can download a [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) from here for implementing flexible view pagers